# Can I use Azure Pipelines Yaml to FTP deploy to different servers depending on the branch?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a `test` branch, and any time I push to it I want azure to build and deploy the web app to our `testing` FTP server we've set up in house.

Now if I merge the changes from `test` into `master`, I want any pushes to the master branch to build in the same way but deploy to our `production` FTP server. Is this possible using Azure Pipelines Yaml? If not, is there any official supported, non-hacky way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the whole process into two stages (build stage and FTP stage).

In YAML ,  you can set it to be triggered by any branch. Then the ‘build stage’ will be triggered by any branches.

In ‘FTP stage’, you could set a condition to filter trigger branches. Then the 'FTP stage' will be triggered by specific branch.

Here is an example:

```
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
     - '*'

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
    - job: 
      steps:
        -  script: echo Building!

- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  jobs:
    - job: 
      steps:
        -  script: echo Building!
```

Here are the docs about [Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and [Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can control which branches get the triggers with a simple syntax.

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: SmartHotel
    source: SmartHotel-CI 
    trigger: 
      branches:
      - releases/*
      - master
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to have the build part of the YAML trigger on any branch, but the FTP part of the yaml trigger on specific branches?